# Dynamical systems resulting from neural networks

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems

Let $F_k$ be the $k$-th layer of a neural network of depth $L$ which is given by
$$F_0=X\qquad F_i=\sigma(W_iF_{i-1}+b_i) \qquad F_L=W_LF_{L-1}+b_L$$
where $X\in\mathbb{R^{d_0\times n}}$, $W_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d_{i}\times d_{i=1}}$, $b_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d_i}$, $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{d_L}$, and $\sigma$ is a nonlinearity, e.g., $\sigma(x)=\tanh(x)$

We are interested in findings parameters $\theta=(W_i,b_i)_{i=1}^{L}$ such that an objective function $\ell$ is minimized. Let's assume $\ell(\theta,X,Y)=(Y-F_L(X))^2_F$, where $F$ is the Frobenius norm. The method of choice is gradient descent, then:
$$W_{i}^{(t+1)}=W_i^{(t)}-\eta \dfrac{\partial\ell}{\partial W_i^{(t)}}$$
$$b_{i}^{(t+1)}=b_i^{(t)}-\eta \dfrac{\partial\ell}{\partial b_i^{(t)}}$$
for $1\leq i \leq L$. This yields a (nonlinear) dynamical system given by that set of equations. Furthermore, if we assume $\eta$ is infinitesimally small then we can get a set of differential equations:
$$\dfrac{d W_i}{dt}=-\dfrac{\partial\ell}{\partial W_i^{(t)}}$$
$$\dfrac{d b_i}{dt}=-\dfrac{\partial\ell}{\partial b_i^{(t)}}$$

I am interested in studying the first or second of equations. I believe currently there is no way to find an analytical solution to those equations, but I would imagine there are some results (theorems) using locality or some extra assumptions. Moreover, in this case everything is in $\mathbb{R}^m$ for some finite $m$ and $\sigma$ is continuous and Lipschitz, so I don't have to worry about pathological spaces/scenarios.

My current mathematical tooling in this area is poor, so I'd like if someone can recommend me a graduate level book that discusses this kind of problem or something as closely related as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Overparameterized Nonlinear Learning: Gradient Descent Takes the Shortest Path?
[https://intra.ece.ucr.edu/~oymak/shortest.pdf](https://intra.ece.ucr.edu/%7Eoymak/shortest.pdf)

Comment: May I ask if you've studied that paper? There are many papers on this topic, but a lot of them use the infinite width limit or something related. I'd like to avoid that kind of argumentation.